# Отзыв о или на?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Немного пошукал и нашёл такое мнение, что говорят *"отзыв **на** что-то",* когда речь идёт об официальном документе, и *"отзыв **о** чём-то",* когда просто высказывают мнение.

Так ли это на самом деле и какие ещё есть нюансы? Может быть, есть случаи, когда подходит только один из предлогов и когда они взаимозаменяемы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре трудностей на "Грамоте" читаем:

> Отзыв – критическая статья, рецензия. Слово отзыв управляет вин. п. и
>   предл. п.
>
> • Вин. п. – отзыв (кого) на что: отзыв (руководителя) на курсовой
>   проект, отзыв (оппонента) на диссертационное исследование. Это
>   управление в некоторых словарях квалифицируется как разговорное
>   (Розенталь, Теленкова, 1999), в других - как нейтральное (Прокопович,
>   1975).
>
> • Предл. п. – отзыв о чем: отзыв о статье, отзыв о дипломной работе.
>
> Различайте: **о**тзыв – критическая рецензия, статья и отз**ы**в –
>   оставление места назначения и прекращение выполнения возложенных на
>   кого-нибудь функций вследствие распоряжения, приказа: отз**ы**в посла,
>   отз**ы**в миссии.

Так что если это  эмоциональный отклик (отзыв) на работу (на произведение), то возможно **НА** - откликнулся на роман и написал свою работу-отзыв. Нужно иметь в виду, что этот термин-своеобразный неологизм, не все учёные воспринимают его как норму. Если же нужна безоговорочная грамотность и классика значения (отзыв - отозвался о чём-то, о ком-то хоть письменно, хоть устно), то лучше употребить предлог **О**. Отзыв о товаре, отзыв о книге, отзыв о поведении кого-то.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! 